# When should I use "parallel" over "parallelism", and vice versa?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, adverbs

I am a bit confused about the words **parallel** and **parallelism**: When and where should one use which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, consider the grammatical class they belong to in order to understand usage better:

- **Parallel** is an **adjective** (see below, if I edit it further, I need to change it too much), a **noun** (`see for example each of the imaginary parallel circles of constant latitude on the earth's surface`) or even a **verb** (*be side by side with something extending in a line*).

When it's an adjective, as you may already know, it's used to classify objects that put side by side have the same distance continuously everywhere.

But it has also other meanings: about *Computing*, for example, it means "involving the simultaneous performance of operations". It can be also related to Music or Grammar.

- **Parallesism** is a noun and its adjective form is **Parallelistic**.

As F'x said, it means: "*the state of being parallel* `or` *of corresponding in some way.*" Also in this case it can refer to other fields, such as computing or poetry.

Comment: @Kejia柯嘉: no prob! :)

Answer (score 2):

- A *parallel* is synonymous with either: “an analog” (or “an equivalent”), “a similarity” or “a comparison”.
- *Parallelism* is the state of being *parallel*, or (in grammar or literature) the use of successive constructions with the same grammatical structure, or (in computer science) the use of parallel processing.

So, if you're discussing mathematics, computer science or literature, odds are you want *parallelism*. For everything else, *parallel* is more likely what you need.